# What mechanism is there to prevent GCP bucket name squatting?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

My company's name is mycomp.

GCP buckets are in a global, public namespace and their names must be publicly unique so all my buckets are prefixed with mycomp.

So mycomp-production, mycomp-test, mycomp-stage, etc.

What is to prevent someone from grabbing mycomp-dev? Like cybersquatting on that bucket name. Something like that could potentially really screw up my organizational structure.

How can I stop or reserve a bucket prefix? Is this even possible? If I want to be an A-hole whats to stop me from grabbing "Nordstrom" or "walmart" if I get their first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCS supports [domain-named buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/domain-name-verification). This would allow you to create buckets like `production.mycomp.com` and `test.mycomp.com`. Since the domain must be owned to create buckets with the domain suffix, it ensures that other people can't create buckets with that naming scheme.

Comment: I wonder if it would be an effective phishing tactic to use somebucket-walmart.com and see if people don't recognize the difference between somebucket.walmart.com. I guess thats always been a problem though for website domain naming in general.